# Capture Images from Camera connected to Computer and listed in Imaging Devices

Tags: delphi, camera, image-scanner

I have a Canon EOS 1000D. When I connect it to computer it listed under Control Panel > Imaging Devices. I want to take picture programmically.

I guess all devices which are listed in Imaging Devices, has a same interface (Maybe TWAIN) and have a standard way to send command to them. Does TWAIN can do that?

Any keyword or information about this is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had good experiences with the Delphi components from Alkenius

[TCamRemote](http://alkenius.no-ip.org/TCamRemote/)

Answer (score 5):

You need the Canon EDSDK. EDSDK stands for EOS Digital Camera Software Development Kit.

EDSDK provides an interface for controlling EOS cameras and for accessing and downloading images.

The EDSDK provides C interfaces. You'll need to find a delphi version, or, if not available, you will need to translate the provided interfaces to Delphi.

You can find EDSDK here if you are european http://www.didp.canon-europa.com/

or here if you are american
http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/eos_slr_camera_systems/eos_digital_slr_cameras/eos_1d?pageKeyCode=downloadSDK&productOverviewCid=0901e0248003d099&id=0901e02480057a74_1&fileURL=ps_sdk_form

Answer (score 1):

Camera, whether Canon /Nikon/ Sony .. should have "Remote Capture" facility to see the image of the pages on your computer screen. Mere TWAIN won't work to use your camera as a scanner.

Hussain KH
Scientist, Library and Information Division
Kerala Forest Research Institute
Thrissur, Kerala, India

hussain.rachana@gmail.com